# Block extensions on domain in Chrome without group policy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want to blacklist all extensions for specific domains so that nothing external runs when opening these urls.

Chrome allows disabling extensions on specific domains, but the guides I found were for [setting it up via Group Policies](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7532015?hl=en), specifically via ["runtime_blocked_hosts"](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9867568?hl=en).

As I am running my browser personally, is there a way these could be set up without GPO and me having to install the Business variant of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I enabled the policy without using the business version of Chrome. Still wondering if this can be done with a config file instead, but here are the steps I followed to make it work on Windows:

1. Download [policy bundle](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7650032?hl=en)
2. Open the file and copy these four files

   %SystemRoot%\PolicyDefinitions\en-US\google.adml
   %SystemRoot%\PolicyDefinitions\en-US\chrome.adml
   %SystemRoot%\PolicyDefinitions\google.admx
   %SystemRoot%\PolicyDefinitions\chrome.admx
3. Modify the policy needed via "Local Group Policy Editor"
4. Reload policies via chrome://policy and clicking reload